# How can I make Clang's "scan-build" work with SCons?

Tags: clang, scons, clang-static-analyzer, scan-build

I've got a project built with [SCons](http://scons.org) and I'm trying to use the [Clang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) to analyze the code. However, when running

```
scan-build scons
```

SCons seems to ignore the settings introduced by `scan-build`. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The way `scan-build` works is it sets up various environment variables that are usually used by build systems (such as `make`) to control how the build happens. Some of these are:

- `CC` - name of program to use as C compiler
- `CXX` - name of program to use as C++ compiler
- `CCC_*` - various environment variables that control the behaviour of Clang's static analyzer

SCons normally cleans out the environment before running a build (this is a feature). In order to make the above environment variables take effect, do something like this in `SConstruct`:

```
env = Environment()
env["CC"] = os.getenv("CC") or env["CC"]
env["CXX"] = os.getenv("CXX") or env["CXX"]
env["ENV"].update(x for x in os.environ.items() if x[0].startswith("CCC_"))
```

Comment: I would add that you should grep for "Environment" in larger SConstruct files to find where the last three lines should go.