# scan-build using scons uses gcc instead of clang

Tags: scons, clang++, clang-static-analyzer

I'm trying to make `scan-build` use clang instead of gcc for compiling, but for some reason `scons` always uses gcc.

If I execute `scons`, I get this:

> ```
> scons: Reading SConscript files ...
> scons: done reading SConscript files.
> scons: Building targets ...
> /usr/bin/clang++ -o src/game.o -c -std=c++1z -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 src/game.cpp
> src/game.cpp:13:62: error: unknown type name 'a'
> constexpr std::array<piece_t, game::pieces_num> game::pieces;a
>                                                              ^
> src/game.cpp:15:7: error: constructor cannot have a return type
> game::game() noexcept {
>       ^~~~
> src/game.cpp:16:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'regen_pieces'
>     regen_pieces();
>     ^
> 3 errors generated.
> scons: *** [src/game.o] Error 1
> scons: building terminated because of errors.
> ```

As you can see, it correctly uses `clang++` instead of `g++`. I achieved this using the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305356/how-can-i-make-clangs-scan-build-work-with-scons) question.

But, if I execute `scan-build scons`, I get this:

> ```
> scan-build: Using '/usr/bin/clang-4.0' for static analysis
> scons: Reading SConscript files ...
> scons: done reading SConscript files.
> scons: Building targets ...
> /usr/bin/../lib/clang/c++-analyzer -o src/game.o -c -std=c++1z -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 src/game.cpp
> src/game.cpp:13:62: error: 'a' does not name a type
>  constexpr std::array<piece_t, game::pieces_num> game::pieces;a
>                                                               ^
> scons: *** [src/game.o] Error 1
> scons: building terminated because of errors.
> scan-build: Removing directory '/tmp/scan-build-2017-04-27-213151-27247-1' because it contains no reports.
> scan-build: No bugs found.
> ```

Because the error messages are different, `scan-build` used gcc instead of clang.

Here is my output for my environment variables:

```
$ printenv | grep clang
CC=/usr/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
```

And my `SConstruct` file:

```
import os
env = Environment()
env["CC"] = os.getenv("CC") or env["CC"]
env["CXX"] = os.getenv("CXX") or env["CXX"]
env["ENV"].update(x for x in os.environ.items() if x[0].startswith("CCC_"))
env["ENV"]["TERM"] = os.environ["TERM"]
env.Append(CXXFLAGS = "-std=c++1z -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3")
env.Append(LIBS = ["pthread"])
env.Program("game", ["src/game.cpp", "src/main.cpp"])
```

So, my question is how can I make `scan-build` use clang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify a compiler, `scan-build` will *not* read the environment variables, but will instead guess. In your case, it guessed that the suitable compiler was gcc.

`scan-build`'s developers are trying to fix this, but in the mean time, you have to explicitly specify the compiler when building:

```
$ scan-build --use-c++=clang++ scons
```